# how can i resize .fig file of matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have different matlab (.fig) files for my plots and I need to re-size them for my publication. My plots have two axes obtained by plotyy function.
I have tried to do re-size manually  but only one axis is changing the other is not.

Here is my rough example to create figure which gives me figure size of around half page of A4 sheet. I want figure of size of around quarter of A4 sheet.

```
a=[1:10]; b=2*(a); c=2*(a); d=2*(a); 
a1=[1:10]; b1=2*(a); c1=2*(a); d1=2*(a); 
figure, 
subplot(2,1,1); 
[AX,H1,H2]=plotyy(a,b,c,d); 
subplot(2,1,2); 
[AX2,H3,H4]=plotyy(a1,b1,c1,d1);
```

Please advise me how to re-size my images.

Comment: Could you post example code of how you create your figure? It doesn't have to contain your data, just show how and by which commands you create the figure. This will help in finding a way to resize the axes as desired.

Comment: Here is my rough example to create figure which gives me figure size of around half page of A4 sheet. I want figure of size of around quarter of A4 sheet. `code`  a=[1:10]; b=2*(a); c=2*(a); d=2*(a); a1=[1:10]; b1=2*(a); c1=2*(a); d1=2*(a); figure, subplot(2,1,1); [AX,H1,H2]=plotyy(a,b,c,d); subplot(2,1,2); [AX2,H3,H4]=plotyy(a1,b1,c1,d1);

Comment: Why not export them to Word or Paint, where you can easily modify the size? Or I didn't understand what you try to do..?

Comment: Hi Adiel, i tried to  reduce size of these figures using paint or GIMP, the resolution of figures is lost.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When I run your code and resize the plot both (i.e. all four) vertical axes scale appropriately. When I save it as a .fig and then open it again in Matlab, the axes still resize properly.

Comment: For saving the high resolution, choose from the figure window File-> Export setup->Rendering, then choose 600, and in Export... choose the format that you want. The file will be bigger but in high resolution. Another option is to do the same with the properties of `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=[1:10]; b=2*(a); c=2*(a); d=2*(a); 
a1=[1:10]; b1=2*(a); c1=2*(a); d1=2*(a); 
figure, 
subplot(2,2,1); %// 1 of 4 Representation 
[AX,H1,H2]=plotyy(a,b,c,d); 
subplot(2,2,2);  %//    2 of 4 Representation
[AX2,H3,H4]=plotyy(a1,b1,c1,d1);
```

[image]

If I understood correctly,you only need to change the subplot command.